# How do you hide the terminals that spawn from subprocess.run?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have packaged my python application into a standalone executable with pyinstaller and every time `subprocess.run` is called, a terminal pops up, then disappears when the command finished executing. This can be quite distracting when dozens of terminals spawn in quick succession. How do I keep these terminals from showing?

### Example

*script.py*

```py
import subprocess
command = ["powershell", "-Command", "Get-ChildItem"]
subprocess.run(command)
```

```
PS> pyinstaller script.py
```

double click on *dist\script\script.exe*

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instantiates [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) and forwards `*popenargs` and `**kwargs` to `Popen`. The keyword argurment [`startupinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTUPINFO) has some flags that can be used to suppress displaying the terminal window. Setting these flags in `startupinfo` successfully hides the windows.

```py
import subprocess 
hide_window = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
hide_window.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
hide_window.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

command = [ ... ]

subprocess.run(command, startupinfo=hide_window)
```